The Ba'al Shem Tov on 'two souls' and two lights joining together
A parable very, very commonly attributed to the Baal Shem Tov (see eg here, here, here) is:

From every human being there rises a light that reaches straight to
heaven. And when two souls that are destined to be together find each
other, their streams of light flow together, and a single brighter
light goes forth from their united being.

Can anyone help me find the source where the Besht is recorded as saying this?
(Someone has asked this before but the story was only traced back to an English anthology, not to the Besht himself.)

If you don't like the other answer, you can offer a bounty on the original question, but this is still a duplicate.
